# Fine Uploader. cancelAll is not a function within onComplate call back. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

This is my onComplete.

```
$('#fine-uploader-house').fineUploader({
...
}).on('complete', function(event, id, name, json) {
    if(!blank(json.cancelAll) && json.cancelAll){
        //$('#fine-uploader-<?=$data['type'];?>').cancelAll();
        //$(this).cancelAll();
        document.getElementById('fine-uploader-<?=$data['type'];?>').cancelAll( );
    }
});
```

I've try to run the cancelAll( ) function multiple ways but always get the same error message.

[FineUploader 3.7.0] Caught exception in 'onComplete' callback - document.getElementById(...).cancelAll is not a function
http://ahm.localhost/jquery.fineuploader-3.7.0/jquery.fineuploader-3.7.0.min.js
Line 16

I cannot seem to find any other information on this and I cannot determine where the fault lies. 
Other than this the uploader is working without any issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: kindly port utl to the plugin you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to call methods on a jQuery plug-in is by passing the name of the method into the plug-in's associated jQuery function.  For example:

```js
$('#someDiv').somePlugin('someMethod', somearg1, somearg2);
```

Fine Uploader is no different.  In this case, you would call `cancelAll` like this:

```js
$(this).fineUploader('cancelAll');
```

This is all covered in [the jQuery plug-in section of Fine Uploader's documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/modes/using-jquery-plugin.html) as well.

Comment: I had been reading much the documentation and could not find any help. Maybe a link from the http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/fineuploaderbasic.html to the page you mention would make it easier. In any case all works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Shane I agree, there probably should be some mention of this on the API page.  I'll add that in a future release.